# What is the effect of partition on below query "Select * from Table_name"

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, database-partitioning

I have implemented database partitioning on my database. The partitioning is done by DBMS_REDEFINITION. The question in my mind is when we execute the select * statement from the table does the partitioning affect the performance.

Tip: We are selecting entire data of a table

What is the difference between `select * from Non_Partitioned_table` and `select * from Partitioned_table`?

Answer (score 1):

Until you have not "Where clause" in your query there is no difference between partitioned and non-partitioned tables.
partition will work on conditions that you do partition with that conditions on tables.
for example when you partition a table by date then every query that have date condition in where clause will be affected.

Answer (score 0):

Partitioning is unlikely to have any affect on a query like `select * from table_name;`

**It won't help performance.**

A common misconception about partitioning is that simply dividing the table into chunks improves performance.  Unless you are taking advantage of a specific partitioning feature, such as partition pruning or partition-wise joins, it's much better to let Oracle
 decide how to divide the work.  For example, with parallel processing, Oracle can just as easily divide up the work into [block range granules](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/parallel002.htm#BEIIGIFH) instead of partition granules.

**It probably won't hurt performance.**

There's a little extra overhead with parsing; more metadata to gather and analyze, more optimizer decisions to evaluate.  In practice I've never noticed a significant difference just from partitioning.  I've definitely seen some unusual behavior with complex partition pruning decisions, but that's not relevant to this simple statement.

There's a little extra data to read; more segments may mean more wasted space.  In practice, with defaults and a normal number of partitions, this extra overhead is not a big deal.  Especially with [deferred segment creation](http://tkyte.blogspot.com/2011/02/deferred-segment-creation.html),  where an empty partition takes up 0 bytes.  Although that feature only works with partitions starting with 11.2.0.2.

But things *can* go very poorly in some extreme examples.  For example, if you set a large and uniform extent size, or disable deferred segment creation, or create a table with thousands of partitions each with only a single row.  In that case, a simple select statement could takes minutes instead of a fraction of a second.